How to reuse WordPress synced patterns across multiple sites in a WordPress network
I have three sites on a WordPress Network.
The first site is the master site and content is copied to the two other child sites.
On my product pages, I use "WordPress Synchronised Patterns".
The patterns work fine on the master site, but not on the child sites.
I get an error message "Block has been deleted or is unavailable."
The reusable block ID that the page linked to in the master site does not exist in the child sites.
I can re-create the pattern on the child site but it will have different IDs.
How can I use the synced pattern on the master site on the child sites?
